# Determining the right buffer size for transmission based on network connection type

Tags: mobile, network-programming

I am in a situation where I can load information onto a buffer over time, and choose the time I put the buffer contents on the network for transmission. I would like to figure out what the best time to trigger the transmission is. For example when the mobile device is connected via Wifi maybe I let the buffer grow to a couple of hundred KB because for example that is how much I can transmit with a single tx 'burst'. On the other hand if the device is connected via the cellular network, I might choose to transmit every 10KB so I can send out the info quickly, reduce the chances of network failures, retransmissions etc while not slowing down my app either.

Does anybody have a way of approximating what those data sizes should be? How much data can I transmit in a single 'burst' based on network type/bandwidth? Is it just as simple as doing a bandwidth test and taking the average of upload throughput? That sounds pretty unscientific to me!